# Do people have extraordinarily long lives in Pillars of Eternity?

Tags: pillars-of-eternity

I'm only at Act 2 yet so I'm not sure if this question could only be answered by some spoiler. However the mission "The Wailing Banshee" looks strange to me: The "banshee" is supposedly pirate Maerwith's mother. However the logbook was written in 2672 AI, while when the game started it was already 2823 AI, meaning that Maerwith was already born and set out as a pirate 150 years ago, and is still alive and active! Does it make sense at all in Eora, or is it more likely an oversight by the script writer?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Maerwith is an elf. And from the Game Manual, we know that :

> Their natural lifespan is typically 200-310 years.